# Change the font in stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to change the font in a table I made in `stargazer()` to Times New Roman and can't figure out how to do that. I made 4 multiple regression models and put them all into a single table.

```
stargazer(reg3FModel1, reg3FModel2, reg3FModel3, reg3FModel4, 
    single.row = TRUE, 
    digits = 2, 
    font.size = "large",
    type = "text", 
    model.numbers = FALSE, 
    dep.var.caption = "Response variables",
    omit.stat = c("rsq", "adj.rsq", "ser", "f", "n"),
    title = "Regression Analysis with 3-Factor Model")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? Because I have to review them.

Answer (score 0):

In `type="html"` there is not font provided but could be added:

```
<style>
  table {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
</style>
```

In `type="latex"` there is also no font. You can set font extra as well, like

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
```

You provided the output `type="text"` that prints output to the console. You can change the font of RStudio in Tools -> Appearance -> Editor Font

If you try to copy paste the output from the console to use it in Word or any other external software, than you have to adjust the font accordingly in that software.